# Failed to compile PHP 8.0.1

Tags: php, compilation

I have a build error when trying to compile the php 8.0.1 from the source code.
The config command is:

```
configure --prefix=/home/abc/ins/php8/ --with-apxs2=/home/abc/ins/apache/bin/apxs
```

The error is as below:

```
/home/abc/Downloads/php-8.0.1/ext/opcache/jit/zend_jit_x86.dasc: In function ‘zend_jit_interrupt_handler_stub’:

/home/abc/Downloads/php-8.0.1/ext/opcache/jit/zend_jit_x86.dasc:1745:25: 

error: ‘executor_globals’ undeclared (first use in this function); 
did you mean ‘executor_globals_id’?
```

Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Do next steps:

1. In the directory with the source files do: `make clean`
2. Add `--enable-opcache` option to your configure script `./configure --enable-opcache`
3. Run `make` again

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your information, but the issue can't be fixed with option --enable-opache.

Comment: I think this might be caused by the option --with-apxs2. If I remove that option, the build can be done successfully. But I don't know why and how to fix that.